# How to make "shaking" animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

In my xcode project I have an UIImage. I want to make it shaking (animation) from left to right a little bit. I wrote this code, however, its not working.

```
-(void)errorShake
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];



    [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-5 * M_PI / 180.0)];
    [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-10 * M_PI / 180.0)];
    [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-15 * M_PI / 180.0)];
    [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-20 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-15 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-10 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-5 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(5 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(15 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(20 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(15 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(10 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(5 * M_PI / 180.0)];
     [lockImage setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0 * M_PI / 180.0)];


    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Could you tell me please, how can I make my image shake ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here's the code I use for that effect.

```
 -(void)shakeView {

        CABasicAnimation *shake = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        [shake setDuration:0.1];
        [shake setRepeatCount:2];
        [shake setAutoreverses:YES];
        [shake setFromValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                                 CGPointMake(lockImage.center.x - 5,lockImage.center.y)]];
        [shake setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:
                               CGPointMake(lockImage.center.x + 5, lockImage.center.y)]];
        [lockImage.layer addAnimation:shake forKey:@"position"];
    }
```

As `Jere` mentioned. Make sure to include the import:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

You can also add it as a category on `UIView`.

Comment: Thanks ! But do I need to add any framework / library to the project ? Xcode gives an error because of first line.

Comment: add the `QuartzCore` framework to your project! and also add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in the file you want to use the animation, or better yet in the apps prefix header file so you can see it from any class.

Comment: Wonderful ! And one more question: what is [self center] ?

Comment: I've edited my answer to fix that. That was for the category implementation.

Comment: Xcode still gives me an error: `Property "center" not found on object of type 'CABasicAnimation'`

Comment: you missed one of the `center.x`'s... but good answer otherwise

Comment: Perfect ! Works fine !
Thanks everyone for help.

Comment: This is such an elegant solution

Answer (score 11):

brynbodayles answer also works under iOS8 for a shake animation in swift.

With Import of QuartzCore:

```
func shakeView(){
    var shake:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    shake.duration = 0.1
    shake.repeatCount = 2
    shake.autoreverses = true

    var from_point:CGPoint = CGPointMake(LoginField.center.x - 5, LoginField.center.y)
    var from_value:NSValue = NSValue(CGPoint: from_point)

    var to_point:CGPoint = CGPointMake(LoginField.center.x + 5, LoginField.center.y)
    var to_value:NSValue = NSValue(CGPoint: to_point)

    shake.fromValue = from_value
    shake.toValue = to_value
    LoginField.layer.addAnimation(shake, forKey: "position")
}
```

Comment: How to stop this animation in between while the shake is repeating

Answer (score 1):

```
func shakeView(_ view: UIView?) {
    let shake = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    shake.duration = 0.1
    shake.repeatCount = 2
    shake.autoreverses = true
    shake.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: (view?.center.x)! - 5, y: view?.center.y ?? 0.0))
    shake.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: (view?.center.x)! + 5, y: view?.center.y ?? 0.0))
    view?.layer.add(shake, forKey: "position")
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Perhaps you can add more details, to explain better the most important parts of your answer. Have a read of [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

From [Corona](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26995004/6619234) answer

**Give shake animation in multiple buttons and also in views SWIFT3**

for view animation just change extension UIButton to extension UIView

```
extension UIButton
{
    func shakeAnim ()
    {
        let shake:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
        shake.duration = 0.1
        shake.repeatCount = 2
        shake.autoreverses = true

        let from_point:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:self.center.x - 5,y: self.center.y)
        let from_value:NSValue = NSValue(cgPoint: from_point)

        let to_point:CGPoint = CGPoint(x:self.center.x + 5,y: self.center.y)
        let to_value:NSValue = NSValue(cgPoint: to_point)

        shake.fromValue = from_value
        shake.toValue = to_value
        self.layer.add(shake, forKey: "position")
   }
}
```