# Programming an animation to loop forever in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I'm using a code snippit from the Stack Overflow post: [How to make "shaking" animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710630/how-to-make-shaking-animation)

I pasted this code into my project and it works perfectly:

```
func shakeView(){
    var shake:CABasicAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    shake.duration = 0.1
    shake.repeatCount = 2
    shake.autoreverses = true

    var from_point:CGPoint = CGPointMake(LoginField.center.x - 5, LoginField.center.y)
    var from_value:NSValue = NSValue(CGPoint: from_point)

    var to_point:CGPoint = CGPointMake(LoginField.center.x + 5, LoginField.center.y)
    var to_value:NSValue = NSValue(CGPoint: to_point)

    shake.fromValue = from_value
    shake.toValue = to_value
    LoginField.layer.addAnimation(shake, forKey: "position")
}
```

I however want this animation to loop until another function is called. How do I make it loop indefinite and how can I make it stop when another function is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, set the [`repeatCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatiming/1427666-repeatcount) to `HUGE_VALF` / [`greatestFiniteMagnitude`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/float/1846834-greatestfinitemagnitude):

> Setting this property to HUGE_VALF will cause the animation to repeat forever.

Second, call `LoginField.layer.removeAllAnimations()` or `LoginField.layer.removeAnimationForKey("position")`when you want to stop the animation.

**Edit**: Apparently Swift does not know `HUGE_VALF`, setting the `repeatCount` to `Float.infinity` should work.

Comment: HUGE_VALF didn't work for me so I used 1e100 instead. You're answer helped me find it on Google though.

Comment: HUGE_VALF won't compile. It gives me the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'HUGE_VALF'

Answer (score 0):

Use shake.repeatCount = Float.infinity